# Parsing : String to XML

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

my API is supposed to take a string and typecast it to XML format.

But i am consistently getting this error :

> ParseError: mismatched tag: line 1, column 764

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetails IssuerId="5" Version="12.2">
    <XMLRequest />
    <BookingDetails  Amount="768"  Comment="Hotel Travel Purchase"  CurrencyCode="INR"  PurchaseType="Hotel"  SupplierName="SomeHotel"  CardAlias="C_ALIAS"  ValidFor="-1D"  CurrencyType="B" />
    <CDFs>
        <CDF FieldName="Order Date" FieldValue="2015-01-01" />
    </CDFs>
    <SomeTag>
        <Rule Action="A" Alias="MyAlias">
            <Controls>
                <OPMCCControl Negate="False"/>
                <OPMIDControl />
                <SomeControlsTags       CumulativeLimit="768"       MaxTrans="None"                 Period="C" />
                <ValidityPeriod           ValidFrom="2015-01-01 00:00:00.0 +0000"          ValidTo="2015-01-11 00:00:00.0 +0000" />
            </Controls>
        </Rule>
    </SomeTag>
</BookingDetails>
<Email  EmailAddress="T@J.COM"/>
<MasterDetails />
```

**Implemented via :**

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(kk.strip()))
```

I know for sure that my XML string is containing all matching tags and is formatted but still something might be missing infront of my eyes!!

Comment: "I know for sure that my XML string is containing all matching tags and is formatted" If you had actually run i through a XML validator, you would have seen that this is not the case.

Comment: @M4rtini : i was actually formatting it via http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-formatter.html and it formed well....so that was one point of assumption! Also, its minified version of a very large XML :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `BookingDetails` tag is self-closed on this line:

```
<BookingDetails  Amount="768"  Comment="Hotel Travel Purchase"  CurrencyCode="INR"  PurchaseType="Hotel"  SupplierName="SomeHotel"  CardAlias="C_ALIAS"  ValidFor="-1D"  CurrencyType="B" />
```

But when there is a separate closing `BookingDetails` element:

```
</BookingDetails>
```

Also, the `<MasterDetails />` is not properly closed on the last line. Should be `</MasterDetails>` instead of `<MasterDetails />`.

---

Note that you can parse this XML in the ["recover" mode](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options) if `lxml.etree` is used:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data, parser=parser))
```

Or, use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with `xml` features:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: @NoobEditor our past will hunt us for a long time, be prepared :D

Comment: BeautifulSoup!! ET is a pile of junk in comparison, out of the box it just worked!

Comment: Note that you can parse this XML in the **recover** mode if lxml.etree.XMLParser is used:
  
  `parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True) `